# problems with WMI asynchronic call

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, wmi-query

if i use the absolute default setup for a WMI asynchronic query:

```
mgtEvWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"); 
mgtEvWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(mgtEvWatcher_EventArrived);
```

is this enough to get a WMI asynchronic query going on? i want to capture the event of process creation.
there are no errors, no exceptions, but whenever i open an application (Tried with cmd->calc and some more i can't remember) nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling the [`ManagementEventWatcher.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.start.aspx) Method? to subscribe to the event

Also if you want to monitor the creation of a process you must use the `__InstanceCreationEvent` wmi class instead.

try this code

```
mgtEvWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"); 
mgtEvWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(mgtEvWatcher_EventArrived); 
mgtEvWatcher.Start();
```

Comment: worked! the event keeps firing non stop though, how can i make it stop firing?. thanks a lot!!! :D

Comment: Just call the Stop method, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.stop.aspx

Comment: Thanks again! I tried the Stop method and it worked partially, i had to set a timeout after the event arrived too. Just writing this in case anybody runs into the same problem.